# Angular custom $update function "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make an update function to replace some data on an user.
I've created the factory:

```
factory('Details', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/client/:id', null, {
        'update': { method: 'PUT'}
    });
}]);
```

and the controller:

```
.controller('ClientDetails', function ($scope, Details, $routeParams) {
    $scope.client = Details.query({ id: $routeParams.id });

    $scope.editClient = function () {
        $scope.client.$update();
    }
});
```

and when entering function `editClient()` it throws and error:
`$scope.client.$update is not a function`

What have I done wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `query` method is defined to return an array of instances: `'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true}`, see documentation for [ng-resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). And the array does not have the `$update` method. From your code, you need to use the `get` to fetch the instance, like this:

```
$scope.client = Details.get({ id: $routeParams.id });

$scope.editClient = function () {
    $scope.client.$update();
}
```

Comment: Yeap! Thanks, that makes sense. But how can I send the updated object into that $update function?

Comment: Never mind that :) i managed to send it to the server but I have an error: E is not a function... ever encountered that?

Comment: My bad :( sorry. I was getting frustrated and I asked before I debugged. .get worked perfectly, my problem was that getting with .query I was displaying the values with client[0].name (...) and so on. And I also had an error on server.